# Instal eslint plugin

Tags: eslint

I have a problem every time I install some eslint-plugin, an error occurs and it fails to install, a few months ago it still works.

**Error Log:**

```
npm i -D eslint-plugin-sort-destructure-keys (or another eslint plugin)
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@ndk%2fenv - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 '@ndk/env@0.0.3' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'eslintcc'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/lenov/.npm/_logs/2021-02-05T09_14_56_820Z-debug.log
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring npm using this

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org`

[npm registry doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/registry)